# Update options in select dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have constructed a **dynamic `select`** using **`jQuery`** like below:

Based on **`YesOrNo`**, I have to show/hide options in **`Source`** and **`Type`**

```
Yes/No          Source               Type
---------------------------------------------
Yes             Yes1 and Yes2        Yes
No              No1 and No2          No1 to 6
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="YesOrNo" name='YesOrNo'>
    <option value=''>Select Yes/No</option>
    <option value='1'>Yes</option>
    <option value='2'>No</option>
</select>
<select id='Source' name='Source'>
    <option value=''>Select Source</option>
    <option data-aob='Yes' value='1'>Yes1</option>
    <option data-aob='Yes' value='2'>Yes2</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='3'>No1</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='4'>No2</option>
</select>
<select id="Type" name='Type'>
    <option value=''>Select Type</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='1'>No1</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='2'>No2</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='3'>No3</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='4'>No4</option>
    <option data-aob='Yes' value='5'>Yes</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='6'>No5</option>
    <option data-aob='No' value='7'>No6</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#YesOrNo').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value === '1') {
        $('#Source option[data-aob=Yes]').show();
        $('#Source option[data-aob=No]').hide();
        $('#Type option[data-aob=Yes]').show();
        $('#Type option[data-aob=No]').hide();
        $("#Source option:selected").prop("selected", false);
        $("#Type option:selected").prop("selected", false);
    } else if (this.value === "2") {
        $('#Source option[data-aob=Yes]').hide();
        $('#Source option[data-aob=No]').show();
        $('#Type option[data-aob=Yes]').hide();
        $('#Type option[data-aob=No]').show();
        $("#Source option:selected").prop("selected", false);
        $("#Type option:selected").prop("selected", false);
    } else {
        $('#Source option').show();
        $('#Type option').show();
        $("#Source option:selected").prop("selected", false);
        $("#Type option:selected").prop("selected", false);
    }
});
```

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubVfa/)

This is working perfect as I expected.  Since the values are obtained from database, I have a problem while displaying the **selected** option in `YesOrNo`.

```
<select id="YesOrNo" name='YesOrNo'>
            <option value=''>Select Yes/No</option>
            <option selected value='1'>Yes</option>
            <option value='2'>No</option>
          </select>
```

Here the option **"Yes"** is selected by default, but here **http://jsfiddle.net/ubVfa/1/** still showing the four options and **`Type`** showing all 7 options.

```
Yes/No                            Source               Type
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Yes(SELECTED by default)          All 4 options        All 7 Options
```

How to tune my code to update the options in `select` dynamically.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: create a function and call it add page load time will solve the issue..

Comment: in chrome it looks fine... ie may not respect hiding `option` eleemnt

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry fiddle got bounced.  check this http://jsfiddle.net/ubVfa/1/

Comment: @DipeshParmar This means once again a `if..else..` block during `onload`?  The code is getting bigger.  Any way to optimize it.

Comment: @user1671639 well you can just one line and do this...add `$('#YesOrNo').trigger('change');` inside top of document.ready block

Comment: @user1671639 your second fiddle also won't work in IE, it displays all options... see my answer below

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ubVfa/4/

Comment: Why don't you try angularjs? It gives you loop and condition support on the HTML side! Here you are trying to achieve it by dom manipulation...

Comment: @Abilash I haven't used Angularjs before.  I'm already using Handlerbarjs for HTML tmpl. Also I'm restricted, anyway I will give a try using angular.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `$("...").change()` after the page is loaded:

```
$(function(){
    $('#YesOrNo').change();
});
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/rXG5N/):

I also hid the options when nothing is selected, calling `$("...").hide()` in the  "onchange" event handler.

The `$(func)` with `func` as an anonymous function is a syntatic suggar for `$(document).ready(func)`, which calls that given function after loading.

The "change" call is just a trigger call, like `$("...").trigger("change")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger to manually invoke the handler on page load.... still your solution will not work in IE... see further changes below

```
var sourceHtml = $('#Source').html();
var typeHtml = $('#Type').html();
$('#YesOrNo').on('change', function () {
    var sources = $(sourceHtml);
    var types = $(typeHtml);
    var aob = $(this).find('option:selected').data('aob');

    if(aob){
        sources = sources.filter('[data-aob="' + aob + '"]');
        types = types.filter('[data-aob="' + aob + '"]');
    }
    $('#Source').empty().append(sources)
    $('#Type').empty().append(types)
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yz4RJ/)

Comment: +1 Yes you're right.  I can't figure out the reason why IE missed it out.  Let me check again and get back.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by **triggering** `change event` on `load`.

just add below code inside `document.ready`

```
$('#YesOrNo').trigger('change');
```

and for test it add `selected="selected"` for No option and run the code.

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubVfa/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If your code logic allows this trigger a change event once.

```
//Triggering a change event on document ready
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#YesOrNo').trigger('change');
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/UrFKk/2/)